# How to solve the Integral $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}}} dx$ with steps

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to solve the Integral $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}}}$dx with steps

I have tried to make the substitution  $\frac{du}{dx}=4-x$ but it seems that there is no continuation road.

I have seen that there is a substitutions that gives the following results.

$\int{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-u}}   \frac{  2i \sqrt{\sqrt{-u}-1}\sqrt{-u}               }{ 1-\sqrt{-u}          }        }     $

But I don see where to start to obtain this result.

Comment: Which steps? What are your own attempts?

Comment: If $y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}}, x=?$

Comment: People aren't too thrilled to see empty topics. Include some of your ideas and point out what you are struggling with. The forum isn't designed for people to solve everything for someone else.

Comment: You seem to think there's a "cookie cutter" method for solving integration problems. Not so. We don't know what you know / what you don't know.

Comment: Ok. Here is your step by step.  

**Step 1: DO SOME WORK AND SHOW IT**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering $$I=\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}}} $$ first let $$\sqrt{4-x}=t^2\implies x=4-t^4 \implies dx=-4t^3\,dt$$ making $$I=-4\int \frac{ t^3}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$ Now, use $$t=\sin(y)\implies dt=\cos(y)\,dy$$ making $$I=-4\int \sin^3(y)\,dy=4\int (1-\cos^2(y))\, d(\cos(y))$$ Just finish !

Comment: I provide a complete answer, and I get a downvote, someone with 90k rep answers, his answer would probably get accepted.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici the last equality seems to come from $\sin^3 y = \sin^2 y\sin y= (1-\cos^2 y)\sin y$, where is the $"\sin y "$ missing?

Comment: @PrashantGokhale well, Claude's answer is also far better than your's. Claude's is in MathJax and is a much cleaner argument. As an (admittedly not always true) rule of thumb, people with more reputation tend to answer better

Comment: @JuanMuñoz It is included in the $d(\cos(y))$. Recall the derivative of the cosine function

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen And the original $dy$ that is missing in the last line is obtained by chain rule apllied to $d(cos(y))$?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Precisely! If you feel like being less rigorous, you could note that $\sin(x)\,dy = \frac{d(\cos(y))}{dy} \, dy = d(\cos(y))$ in some sense. Of course, as you note, this is just the chain rule :)

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I can notice it. Using the adittional dy's above and under gives a better understanding of the chain. I wonder why Claude preffer to use this notation, it seems that is becouse is shorter notation but maybe Im missing any other reason?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz the notation tells you what substitution to make! Here we can let $u=\cos(y)$ and the notation above makes this a bit more obvious... normally you would start with $\sin(y)dy$ at the end and thus in making the substitution $u = \cos(y)$  Claude would either have to skip the details of the substitution (i.e. that the $\sin(y)$ at the end gets wrapped into the differential), try to jam the notation in there somewhere to alert the reader to that, break up the flow to explain it in words, or write it like Claude did, which alerts the reader to the substitution needed and what gets...

Comment: wrapped into the differential. This can also make it easier to check work in some situations, though I would personally still include a line on my scratch paper with $\sin(y)dy$ and THEN write $d(\cos(y))$ beneath it for clarity's sake. As an example of this, notice how the last integral has the sign flipped (since the derivative of cosine is negative sine) but no intermediate step showed this. In simple cases like this though, not having to write that out comes with practice.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}}$

$x=\dfrac{3 u^4+2 u^2-1}{u^4}$

$dx=\dfrac{4-4 u^2}{u^5}$

and the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{4-4 u^2}{u^4} \, du=4 \int \left(\frac{1}{u^4}-\frac{1}{u^2}\right) \, du=4 \left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{3 u^3}\right)+C$$

$$\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}} \left(\sqrt{4-x}+2\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $3<x\leq4$.

Let $x=4\sin^2t$, where $t\in\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Hence, $\cos{t}=\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{4}}$, $dx=8\sin{t}\cos{t}dt$ and $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}}dx=\int\frac{8\sin{t}\cos{t}}{\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}}dt=-8\int\frac{\cos{t}}{\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}}d(\cos{t})=$$
$$=-8\int\frac{\cos{t}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}}d(\cos{t})=4\int\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}d(\cos{t})-4\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}}d(\cos{t})=$$
$$=-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{(1-2\cos{t})^3}+4\sqrt{1-2\cos{t}}+C=$$
$$=-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\left(1-\sqrt{4-x}\right)^3}+4\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}+C.$$

Comment: $\pi/4$ is in the range you defined for $t$ hence we have for $t=\pi/4$, that $x=2$ which is not in the domain. All in all the domain doen't matter here :-)

Comment: @Math-fun I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome :-)